# Is a comma still required before the name of the addressee when there's a tag question?

Tags: punctuation

For a sentences like "You're a good person, Tom." and "You're a good person, aren't you?" There's no doubt the commas are required.  But what about:

"You're a good person, aren't you, Tom?"

Are both of these commas required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, because that is how you know it is the [vocative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocative_case).

Note that if you say

> "You're a good person, aren't you Tom?"

it looks like you're asking if the person's name is Tom.